# A singleton object's instance is not injected in a scoped instantiated object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have the following two classes:

```
public class MyScoped : IMyScoped
{
   private readonly ITransaction _transaction;

   public MyScoped(ITransaction transaction)
      => _transaction = transaction;

   public void Apply()
   {
     if(_transaction.Commit)
     {
        SaveToDatabase();
     }
   }
}

public class Transaction : ITransaction
{
   public bool Commit{get;set;}
}
```

I wired up these two classes like this:

```
services
 .AddSingleton<ITransaction,Transaction>()
 .AddScoped<IMyScoped,MyScoped>()
```

Somewhere before calling the instance of MyScoped class, I set "Commit" to `true` like the following code:

```
_transaction.Commit = true;
_myScoped.Apply();
```

But it's always `false` when examining `if(_transaction.Commit)` condition and hence the transaction is not committed. What have I done wrong?!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown here, the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: When I changed the way that the Transaction object is wired up, the code started working but the initial code posted earlier had to work too! Could it be a bug to be filed with Microsoft?

```services.AddSignleton<ITransaction>(new Transaction());```

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Your current code works for me. Did you inject `ITransaction` like `    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMyScoped _myScoped;
        private readonly ITransaction _transaction;
        public HomeController(IMyScoped myScoped, ITransaction transaction)
        {
            _myScoped = myScoped;
            _transaction = transaction;
        }
`